# Как сказать «является нормальным, неошибочным поведением и так всё и задумано» одним словом?

Tags: выбор-слов, переводы

Нужно переформулировать и уточнить такую фразу:

> Обозначает, что заявленное поведение не считается ошибкой.

Сейчас неясно, а чем же считается?

Хочу исключить отрицание и сформулировать это **одним словом**. В аналогичном [англоязычном тексте](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign/info) используется [intentional](https://slovari.yandex.ru/intentional/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/), [intended](https://slovari.yandex.ru/intended/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/), обозначающие «преднамеренный, намеренный; умышленный»:

> This tag indicates that the specified behavior is intentional.

## Смысл, который я хочу передать.

> В данном случае сайт ведет себя именно так, как должен. Варианты:
>
> > *Почему сайт не виден, когда я отключаю компьютер?*
>
> Это обусловлено устройством сайта, браузера или интернета вообще.
>
> > *Почему я не могу голосовать за свой ответ?*
>
> Это часть функционала сайта. Ограничение есть потому, что так задумано, это часть функционала сайта, так и должно быть.

Этот смысл нужно передать в одно, максимум — два слова.

## Почему не подходят слова из словаря

Меня смущает то, что «намеренный» предполагает некоторый источник намерения. В данном случае это команда разработчиков в целом, но нельзя утверждать, что кто-то намеренно сделал это именно так. В некоторых случаях это просто так получилось.

Более того, как мне кажется, слово «намеренно» имеет оттенки смысла «специально», «вопреки», даже «назло». Еще хуже с «преднамеренно» и тем более с «умышленно» (которое вызывает ассоциации с УК РФ).

Здесь такие смыслы необходимо полностью исключить. Пользователь не должен подумать, что какое-то ограничение сайта выдумано ему назло.

Comment: Вместо "не считается" обычно пишут "не является".

Comment: @Artemix: да, действительно лучше звучит. Спасибо, заменил.

Comment: Вот мне интересно, за что минус-то поставили? Хоть бы комментарий какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы перевел так:

> Обозначает, что описанное поведение соответствует ожидаемому.

или

> Обозначает, что описанное поведение соответствует задуманному.

Последний вариант мне нравится тем что лучше соответствует самому понятию "by design".

Comment: Такое поведение и было задумано.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign/info результат.

Answer (score 1):

- соответствует правилам.

  > По правилам сайта, пользователь не может голосовать за свой собственный ответ.
- соответствует спецификации.

  > В данном случае, согласно спецификации сайта, пользователю должно быть послано сообщение по почте.

Upd. А почему, собственно, мы все пишем на канцелярите?

> Тег <kbd>так-и-было-задумано</kbd> обозначает, что описанное поведение правильно.
>   Возможно, его решили считать правильным после этого сообщения.

Comment: По ссылке объясняется значение тега, которым отмечаются сообщения о поведении форума (например этого), которые пользователь считает странными, а администрация говорит "так и надо". В том числе ситуации, когда о подобном поведении сайта никто раньше не думал и не замечал, но теперь, когда пользователи это заметили, было решено что "так и надо". Т.е. спецификация тут точно не подходит.

Comment: @Artemix, почему же, вот прямо сейчас и дописали спецификацию. Я как программист говорю :)

Comment: Про [meta-tag:так-и-было-задумано]: это служебная метка, их вроде как нельзя переименовывать. Аналогично с обязательными. А раз вы программист, приходите к нам на ru.stackoverflow.com =)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, это интересная мысль! А на чем вы пишете?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы перевел как "является допустимым"

*Обозначает, что заявленное поведение является допустимым.*

Answer (score 1):

"Штатное поведение"? Мы в переписке с пользователями по техподдержке часто используем этот термин.

Comment: Кстати, интересный вариант. Пока что у нас такой текст получился: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE/info

Comment: Тем более! По-моему среди разработчиков ПО это знакомый термин, и он не вызовет никакого удивления. Штатное/нештаное поведение системы часто встречается в документации (и что важно, в ТЗ от заказчика, значит и он знаком с этими словами).

Comment: подумаю насчет того, чтобы немного переделать описание метки. Кстати, приходите на Ru.SO )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо за приглашение. Я там есть. И на англоязычном тоже.

Answer (score 0):

## Соответствует предполагаемому

> Обозначает, что заявленное поведение соответствует предполагаемому.

Пока что использовал такой вариант.

- Понятно ли, кем предполагаемое?
- Понятно ли, что «предполагаемое» — это не «Мы предполагали, что такая ошибка когда-нибудь произойдет», а «Мы предполагали, что сайт будет работать именно так. Хорошо, что так он и работает»?

Comment: Вместо "предполагаемому" лучше "ожидаемому". А у слова intended  есть еще перевод "задуманный", хорошо подходит к английскому "by design". Больше вариантов перевода здесь: http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=intended&l1=1

Comment: @Artemix: опубликуете как ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Почему просто не сказать "нормально"? "Поведение является нормальным, это не ошибка или неисправность".

Слово "нормально" действует на пациентов успокаивающе :~)

Аэрокосмический вариант: "проходит в штатном режиме" ("5 секунд, полёт **нормальный**")

Comment: Насчёт "как задумано": именно в русском языке есть потрясающей силы выражение: "хотели как лучше - а получилось как всегда"  Как всегда - значит нормально, штатно, правильно.